# Py2app and Py2exe fail to package Patsy files

Tags: exception, py2exe, py2app

I have been building a python-based standalone application using py2app (Mac OS X 10.6) and py2exe (Win XP and Win7). Recently I added support for functions that depend on the library patsy. However, when building py2app or py2exe versions of my software, only the "**init**.pyc" and "origin.pyc" files from patsy are included in the site-packages.zip patsy folder (excluding the 20 additional python module files). When importing patsy, the standalone app throws the error "ImportError: No module named highlevel" (highlevel is patsy module).

An ugly work around for this is to throw the missing .pyd modules into the patsy directory of the site-packages.zip, but this is not ideal. A simple example of this for py2app code is shown, but the same applies for py2exe:

test_import.py

```
import patsy
print 'hello patsy'
```

setup.py

```
includes = ["patsy"]

from distutils.core import setup
import py2app
import patsy
from patsy import highlevel

options = {"py2app":{"includes": includes}}
setup(name='test',app=["test_import.py"],setup_requires=["py2app"])
```

Any recommendations are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that patsy is slightly over-clever in how it defines its main namespace, see the end of `patsy/__init__.py`:

```
def _reexport(modname):
    __import__(modname)
    mod = sys.modules[modname]
    for var in mod.__all__:
        __all__.append(var)
        globals()[var] = getattr(mod, var)
for child in ["highlevel", "build", "constraint", "contrasts",
              "desc", "design_info", "eval", "origin", "state",
              "user_util", "missing", "splines"]:
    _reexport("patsy." + child)
```

This avoids a bunch of copy/paste code duplication but messes up py2exe and py2app's heuristics for figuring out which files are in use; because there's no explicit literal import statement, they can't "see" that all those modules are in fact getting imported. The *real* solution is for py2exe/py2app to catch up with the last 5 years of python infrastructure development and trust packages' setup.py to install only what's needed.

In the mean time, this is a very standard problem so both packages have ways to work around it, e.g. for py2app these appear to be called "recipes": http://pythonhosted.org/py2app/recipes.html

Edit: Alternate solution: use the just-released patsy 0.2.1, which has a slightly less clever `__init__.py` which should Just Work.

Comment: Thanks Nathaniel! Updating (or should I say downgrading?) to patsy 0.2.1 did the trick. Thanks for your responsiveness.